# Ionic push notifications api returns status 410. ¿Alternatives?

Tags: ionic-framework, push-notification, ionic2, firebase-cloud-messaging, cordova-plugins

I have been reading some forums and i found that ionic services are deprecated. Now developers have to find another alternatives for push and auth services. For push notifications there are alternatives such Firebase and Onesignal plugins.

*I have to say that my proyect was using Ionic1 and implemented phonegap-plugin-push (~1.10.2).* **What should I use? and
What does it involve?**

[image]

https://blog.ionicframework.com/sunsetting-ionic-cloud-push-and-auth/
https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-pro-an-push-notifications-shutdown-of-ionic-push/102813

Answer (score 0):

For push services, you can still use [Ionic Native Push](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/push/), which is a wrapper for phonegap-plugin-push in Ionic 3. It uses Google Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) in the back end. See [this page](https://engineering.hexacta.com/managing-push-notifications-with-ionic2-3698249c07a) for a discussion on how to do it. I have been using Ionic Native Push successfully in Ionic 3.